# Isolating causal effect

Tags: causality, group-differences, dependent-variable

we are going to have kids working together. So for example, there could be 20 groups of 3 students each. What we would be interested in seeing is if the presence of particular students affects the grades of others either positively or negatively. So after all 20 groups perform their assignments and are given individual student grades, they would switch teams and repeat. So we should be able to see if particular students have a greater positive/negative effect on other students I am curious to see if there are any ideas on how to best measure the effect once we have the data. So the names of all the different groups and the grades (1-10 scale) for the students. Students would be given individual grades not group grades. And for simplicity, the assumption is there are no other variables other than the kids in each group.

Comment: Are they triaded up at random? How many rounds will there be out of 34220 possible?